# How do I find the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{R/Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've started a solution as:

Let $r + \mathbb{Q}$ be of finite order ($r \in \mathbb{R}$). Then $n(r+\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q} \implies nr \in \mathbb{Q} \implies r\in \mathbb{Q}.$

But then from here on I wonder what conclusions can I draw. Does $T(\mathbb{R/Q})=\mathbb{Q}?$

Comment: $T(\mathbb{R/Q})=0$ is the conclusion.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I can't see how.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. As you've noted real number $r \in \mathbb R$ having finite order $n$ modulo $\mathbb Q$ is rational. Conversely, any rational number $q$ is $0 + \mathbb Q$ in the quotient. Hence $T(\mathbb R/\mathbb Q) = 0 + \mathbb Q$ (the zero element in $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$).